# unwindしながらactionメソッドを使いたい

Tags: swift, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Xcode8.3.1
iOS 10.3
Swift3
NavigationControllerでpush segueを使って画面遷移をしています。
遷移先のbuttonを押すとunwindして親画面に戻るようにしたのですが、その際buttonに紐づけたactionメソッドが実行されなくて困っています。
viewWillDisappearを使って見たのですが、親のViewのViewWillAppearより後に呼ばれてしまうため、他の方法を探しています。

遷移先のbuttonが押された際にunwindしながら、遷移先で処理を実行するか、値を親のViewに渡すかしたいのですがどのような方法があるでしょうか。

**追記**
コメントを見て色々試して見た結果、遷移先のNavigationBarに直接buttonを配置して、Action及びunwindを設定するとダメでした。
一度NavigationBar以外のところに設置してからActionとunwindを紐づけて、その後NavigationBarに入れると動きます。
ただ、なぜそうなるのかがよくわかりません。

Comment: 「遷移先のbuttonを押すとunwindして親画面に戻るようにしたのですが、その際buttonに紐づけたactionメソッドが実行されなくて」というのは、おかしい挙動です。現在開発中のプロジェクトからいったん離れて、ただ`UINavigationController`ベースで画面遷移するだけの、サンプルプロジェクトを作成し、Segueで遷移し、Unwind Segueで戻るStoryboardの編集をして、Unwindのアクションメソッドが動作するか、確認してみてください。そのアクションメソッドが呼ばれないのでしたら、そのコードをここに掲示してください。期待通り呼ばれたら、開発中のプロジェクトと比較して、差異を探してみましょう。その差異の中に、原因があるはずです。

Comment: 「遷移先のbuttonを押すとunwindして親画面に戻るようにしたのですが、その際buttonに紐づけたactionメ‌​ソッドが実行されなくて」別の方のコメントと同様ですが、これは紐づいているなら実行されないのはおかしいです。本当に紐づけができているかどうか確認できますか？　あるいは「actionメソッドは実行されるが、期待した動作にならない」ことを「actionメソッドが実行されない」とおっしゃられていないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

追記をいただいて、初めて問題の所在がわかりました。結論を先に述べますと、 **`UINabvigationBar`には、`UIButton`ではなく、`UIBarButtonItem`を配置してください。** 現状では、Unwindだけでなく、いかなるアクションメソッドもConnectできません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Storyboard上で、ナビゲーションバーに、`UIButton`をドラッグして配置することができます。配置するとどうなっているか、ビューの階層状態を、確認してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上図のように、`UIBarButtonItem`の上に、`UIButton`が載っていることがわかります。この状態で、右クリック（Controlキー＋クリック）してドラッグで、Connectすると、`UIButton`からでなく、その下の`UIBarButtonItem`がConnect元となります。現状でも、Document Outlineから操作すれば、`UIButton`から引っ張ることができますが、むだに`UIButton`と`UIBarButtonItem`の二段重ねになっていることを考えると、そもそも`UIButton`を使わないという選択が合理的だと思います。
（`UINavigationBar`にボタン以外の、たとえば`UISearchBar`などの`UIControl`サブクラスを配置したい要請があることを、考慮して、`UIBarButtonItem`以外も配置できることになっているのでしょう。）